# Creating menu bar link for jquery tabify div id

Tags: jquery, html

I have planned to use **jquery tabify** in my project so I created the tabify the following code

```
<div id="tabs">
    <ul>
        <li><a href="#tabs-1">First</a></li>
        <li><a href="#tabs-2">Second</a></li>
        <li><a href="#tabs-3">Third</a></li>
    </ul>
    <div id="tabs-1">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.</div>
    <div id="tabs-2">Phasellus mattis tincidunt nibh. Cras orci urna, blandit id, pretium vel, aliquet ornare, felis. Maecenas scelerisque sem non nisl. Fusce sed lorem in enim dictum bibendum.</div>
    <div id="tabs-3">Nam dui erat, auctor a, dignissim quis, sollicitudin eu, felis. Pellentesque nisi urna, interdum eget, sagittis et, consequat vestibulum, lacus. Mauris porttitor ullamcorper augue.</div>
</div>
<script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){
      $("#tabs").tabs();
      if($("#tabs") && document.location.hash){
            $.scrollTo("#tabs");
        }
      $("#tab ul").localScroll({ 
        target:"#tabs",
        duration:0,
            hash:true
        });
    });
  </script>
```

This works without any issue .. thanks jquery tabs.

but currently I need to pass this tabs url in my menu link

so created the menu link like this

```
<nav>
<ul>
<li><a href="index.html" >Home</a></li>
            <li><a href="contact.html" >Contact US</a></li>
<li><a href="about.html" >About Us</a>
                  <ul>
                  <li><a href="about.html#company"> Company Review</a></li>
                <li><a href="about.html#vision">Our Vision</a></li>


              </ul>
                </li>

</ul>
</nav>
```

The about us company link `(about.html#companny & about.html#vision)` on menu clik doesn't work

**What I need to do to make it work ? Thanks.**

Comment: Your divs with name company, vision dont exist you need create your divs or change name to tabs-1 to company .. and so on

Comment: i have change tab-1 tab-1 with my relevant id which i have decleared in my menu link ///